# How do I create a source and header file at once on VS?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio

I've just recently changed from MacOS/Xcode to Windows/VS so I'm a little confused on how to do some things, but I was wondering how I could create a source file with a matching header at the same time instead of doing each file separately. XCode on Mac asks if you also want to create a header with the source file but I cant seem to see that anywhere on VS.

Am using Win11 and the latest version of VS.

Comment: Just to clarify you are using Visual Studio Community 2022 and not VSCode. There is a different tag for VSCode and its behavior is very different from Visual Studio.

Comment: @drescherjm yes VS Community

Answer (score 1):

I have done it by pressing Ctrl+Shift+X when C++ project is selected in solution explorer of Visual Studio. It should open a class wizard where you can add new or modify existing C++ classes.

Comment: Is there not a simpler way of doing this or being able todo this from the new file selection?

Comment: Maybe with some kind of plugin I don't have. What I have seen is that we can just make totally empty file named automatically like "Source1.cpp"  or "Header1.h" from File->New->File... and that is usually nothing like what I want to do.

Answer (score 0):

1. Properties:`Add New Item`->`C++ Class`
2. Click `OK`.

Or

Create a .h file from function in cpp file:

1. Click the function name to highlight it.
2. `ALT+SHIFT+F10`-> `Create Declaration/Definition`

Maybe there are other plugins can do it.